# Linked list temp changes automatically

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am having trouble understanding why `temp` is changing its value from 9 to 1 after the statement:

```
last->data = (*head_ref)->data;
```

My current goal is to reverse the data in the first and last node of a linked list containing 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9.

The result that I am getting is 9, 3, 5, 7, 9.

If `temp` is equal to last which is equal to `head_ref`, would altering last affect `temp` even though I didn't set `temp = last` after changing last?

```
void reverseNode(struct Node** head_ref)
{
    struct Node *last = *head_ref;
    while(last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
    struct Node *temp = last;
    printf("%d ", temp->data);      // temp->data = 9
    last->data = (*head_ref)->data;
    printf("%d ", temp->data);      // temp->data = 1
    (*head_ref)->data = temp->data;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: In this statement `struct Node *temp = last;` the pointer is the same as `last` and you're changing the data of `last` so the `temp` reflects that change. That is what you are seeing.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score -1):

```
void reverse(){
struct node *first=NULL,*second=start,*third=start->next;
if(start==NULL){
    printf("No Element to Reverse\n");
}else{
    while(second!=NULL){
        second->next=first;
        first=second;
        second=third;
        if(third!=NULL){
            third=third->next;
        }
    }

    start=first;
}
display(); }
```

This code will reverse the whole linked list without losing the data.

Comment: Recommendations must come with rationale. Code-only answers do not.